# Phonecat tutorial app (too much dependencies?)

Tags: node.js, angularjs

So I'm learning AngularJS via the official website. There is a tutorial where the final app is a catalog of Android devices. Ok, so I've cloned the repo and the final size is `14 MB`. That's nice. Then I download all the dependencies using `npm install` and now the final size of the app directory is `92 MB`.

So my question is: is this normal for an app like this? I mean, the app is not too complex. I'm just starting with Angular (and by the way, with node) so maybe I'm downloading innecessary packages and I don't even know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal and (maybe) okay. Some node modules come with other dependencies e.g. [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) that has 22 other dependencies and so on. The bundled npm packages from NPMJs.org contain sometimes unittests, documentation (generated or plain markdown) or examples, but I wouldn't worry about the filesize.